# Check if model exists even if it's not present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm stuck on something and have no idea what to do. In my reservations controller I have:

```
if Invitation.exists?
```

which returns true when '/events/1/invitations/2/reservations' is called, as expected, but returns:

```
'Couldn't find Invitation without an ID'
```

when '/events/1/reservations' is called, also expected. I need a way to though to check if it exists when the 2nd url is called and in order to bypass the initiation if @invitation.

I'm very new to rails so any advice here would be welcome.

Thanks

---EDIT---

I think I may have given too little information.

Basically there are two URLs I want to use:

1st is example.com/events/1/invitations/2/reservations - in order to have the reservations index display all reservations that belongs to a given invitation, in this case '2'.

2nd is example.com/events/1/reservations - in order to display all reservations that belong to an event.

So in the reservations controller index action I have:

```
@event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
@reservations = Reservation.all

if Invitation.exists?
  @invitation = Invitation.find(params[:invitation_id])
  @invite = true
else
end
```

and in the reservations view index I have:

```
<% if @invite == true%>
  <% @invitation.reservations.each do |reservation| %>
    ...
<% else %>
  <% @event.reservations.each do |reservation| %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

So basically if the 2nd URL is used I can't use 'Invitation' in the controller action as it gives this error: "Couldn't find Invitation without an ID", so I need a way to tell the controllers if statement that if no invitation id is present (in the URL?) don't initiate @invitation.

Hope that's clearer, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a the model constant here instead of the actual instance of the model, which is what you're probably expecting. You want something more like:

```
@invitation = Invitation.find(params[:id])
```

And then continue going on if the invitation is found.

-- edit --

I think I get what you're trying to do here. Try this:

```
def index
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @invitation = Invitation.find(params[:invitation_id]) if params[:invitation_id]
    @reserations = Reservation.all
    ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this won't help me though as it still references 'Invitation' that causes the problem when I access via URL 2 - see edit.

Comment: Thanks for your edit to your reply to my edit. Anyone smell a woodchuck?

Answer (score 1):

Your post isn't completely clear, but do you want this?

```
@invitation = params[:invitation] if params[:invitation]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `find` method throw exception upon no data. You should use `find_by_*` method if you don't want this behavior, i.e.

```
@invitation = Invitation.find_by_id(params[:invitation_id])
```

Other issues with your code:

- The `Invitation.exists?` call simply checks if there are any rows in `invitations` table. I am assuming that is not what you want. You have to supply an id/or conditions as input to check for specific object existence.  Read the [exists?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists?/class) documentation for more details.
- I would refactor your code as follows:

Assuming this is your data model:

```
class Event
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :invitations
end

class Reservation
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :invitation
end

class Invitation
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :reservations            
end
```

Change your controller code:

```
@event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
@reservations = if params[:invitation_id].present?
  (@invitation = @event.invitations.find([:invitation_id])).reservations
else
  @event.reservations
end
```

Modify the view code to access the `@reservations` list:

```
<% @reservations.each do |reservation| %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed, specifically:

    if params[:invitation_id].present?

and thanks for the coding tips too.